# E2E mock $httpBackend doesn't actually passThrough for me

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Although I believe I'm following the [instructions here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend) for setting up $httpBackend to pass selected requests to the server, it's not working for me.

[**Here is a Plunkr with a failing test**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FtWs9GUUK1KuFeitwUKX) that shows what I'm doing and explains in comments what seems to be going wrong.

My spelunking suggests that, for some reason, the mock `$httpBackend` doesn't have an inner copy of the real `$httpBackend` so that, when it comes time to pass through the XHR request, it passes it to the mock `$httpBackend` instead. That second call throws an exception because it doesn't know what to do with the request.

### Response to dtabuenc

I remember with appreciation your post on midway testing. You identify an important range of integration testing that falls between unit- and E2E-testing. I am standing on that middle ground.

I don't think you are being snarky at all. Your answer is perfect reasonable ... or it ***would be reasonable*** if it weren't contradicted by the text of the "[API reference / ngMockE2E / $httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.%24httpBackend)". I quote:

> This implementation can be used to respond with static or dynamic responses via the `when` api and its shortcuts (`whenGET`, `whenPOST`, etc) and ***optionally pass through requests to the real `$httpBackend` for specific requests (e.g. to interact with certain remote apis or to fetch templates from a webserver)*** ...
>
> [I]n an end-to-end testing scenario *or in a scenario when an application is being developed with the real backend api replaced with a mock*, it is often desirable for certain category of requests to bypass the mock and ***issue a real http request*** .... To configure the backend with this behavior use the `passThrough` request handler of when instead of `respond`.[emphasis mine].

The documentation is silent on the matter of E2E `$httpBackend` usage within a Jasmine environment. I can't think of a reason to preclude it. If there is such a reason they should state it clearly. Seriously, who reads about a *mock* component and doesn't anticipate using it in a test environment?

To "*pass through requests to the real `$httpBackend` for specific requests, e.g. to interact with certain remote apis*" is precisely what I intend to do. What could they possibly mean by "real $httpBackend" except the non-mock version of that component?

I do not understand your claim that

> The `ngMocksE2E` module is designed to be used on the "server" side of things where the actual angular application is executing.

The word "server" appears exactly 3 times on that page, not once suggesting that *any* application code would be executed on a "server". I don't know what you mean by the "actual angular application" executing on "the 'server' side of things."

The documentation is perfectly clear that the E2E `$httpBackend` is not limited to E2E testing. It is also for "*a scenario when an application is being developed with the real backend api replaced with a mock*".

That's just a half step away from my scenario in which *an application is being **tested** with the real backend api*."

In my scenarios, the SUT is calling upon a component which fetches data from a server. My tests exist to verify that this dependent component succeeds in making such requests of the real backend and will retrieve or save data in the expected manner. This is an integration test that cannot be adequately satisfied by mocking the behavior of the backend.

> Of course I can test (and do test) with mock XHR responses the component's ability to respond properly to what I *predict* will be the backend's behavior. That is not the same as validating that the component responds appropriately to the *actual* backend's behavior ... which might change as the application evolves and depart from the mocked responses in some significant way.

I would consider using your midway tester for this purpose if I understood how to swap it into the SUT's code path. I don't. I think the component making XHR requests is inaccessible to your `ngMidwayTester`. But I do know how to jam a real XHR helper into the pipeline if I have to.

**Here is where I stand at the moment**.

Either someone can show how to make `$httpBackend` pass certain requests through to the server - as the documentation proclaims it can - or I will replace the `passThrough` implementation myself with a working XHR implementation.

I prefer the first option. If driven to the second, I shall offer a link to it here for the benefit of others who share my needs and my interpretation of the API documentation.

Is there a 3rd way I'm missing?

Comment: Did you ever proceed with the second option? I have this exact same issue and I'd be interested in the details of the solution you eventually went with.

Comment: Yes. I've stopped going this route. I'm using the ["ngMidwayTester"](https://github.com/yearofmoo/ngMidwayTester) by Matias Niemelä. Need to document this. You can see some working examples in the [Zza Sample async tests](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/tree/master/node/zza-node-mongo/client/test/specs.async).

Comment: @Ward is it possible to use ngMidwayTester with ngResource? I tried to use it but I can't seem to mock $httpBackend

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following is an explanation of the purpose of the `$httpBackend` that is in the `ngMockE2E` module.

The `ngMockE2E` module is simply not designed nor intended to be used from within a jasmine specification.

When doing end-to-end testing there are two sides to the test. One is the angular application that is being tested, the other is the angular-scenario code that lives in the Jasmine Specification.

Under E2E tests there are no angular module, or ng-mocks, or anything angular-related on the jasmine side of things (other than the scenario runner).

The `ngMocksE2E` module is designed to be used on the "server" side of things where the actual angular application is executing. It's main purpose is to enable us to pre-can responses so that integration-level UI testing can proceed much quicker than if each page actually went to the server for JSON.

When using jasmine along with `ng-mocks`,  angular will always replace the $httpBackend with the mock backend. When adding the `ngMocksE2E` module it will not be able to get ahold of any "real" `$httpBackend` and as you have already found out, will just wrap the mock and delegate to it on the pass-through.

It would seem that the kind of test you are trying to write is a test that doesn't test the UI integration, but tests the application javascript and server integration.

This is perfectly legitimate style of testing (referred to some as 'midwayTesting' in the angular community). Your problem is you are using the wrong tool.

I would take a look at this:

https://github.com/yearofmoo/ngMidwayTester

Which you would use instead of angular-mocks and angular.module() in order to facilitate the kind of testing I'm assuming you want to do.

You can read more about it here:

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html

(apologies if you have already been linked there)

**EDIT:** (To address additional comments in question)

You have a real beef in that the documentation is not clear that `ngMockE2E` cannot be used on the client (i.e. karma/jasmine) side of an end-to-end testing setup.  It is not unreasonable to interpret things like you have interpreted them, but it doesn't change the fact that the interpretation is wrong.

The ngMockE2E will pass through requests if instructed when used on the server side of an application rather than on the client side. This is meant so that you can still pass through certain requests that are hard to mock as pre-canned responses. What I mean by client and server-side is that in end-to-end testing there are two ends. You have the application to be tested which is served by a standard application server, and you have the test code that is driving the application usually executing in Karma or another test runner, which uses standard HTTP requests to communicate to the application which is executing in another process.

If you look at the documentation and how to setup `ngMockE2E` you will notice there is no mention of Jasmine, and the instructions are for how to set up in a real angular application:

```
myAppDev = angular.module('myAppDev', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
myAppDev.run(function($httpBackend) {
  phones = [{name: 'phone1'}, {name: 'phone2'}];

  // returns the current list of phones
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(phones);

  // adds a new phone to the phones array
  $httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method, url, data) {
    phones.push(angular.fromJson(data));
  });
  $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/templates\//).passThrough();
  //...
});
```

As you can see in this example, they are mocking all the JSON data instructions, while letting it still fetch the templates from the server.

In order to use it from jasmine the setup would be quite different, using `angular.mock.module('ngMockE2E')` and then setting up the `$httpBackend.whenGET()` in a `beforeEach()` rather than in a `module.run()`.

As far as `ngMidwayTester` I linked you to, I believe this would, in fact, be compatible with `ngMockE2E`. Essentially `ngMidwayTester` replaces `angular.mock.module()` and `inject()` with it's own implementations. So you could use it like this:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  tester = ngMidwayTester('app', 'ngMockE2E');
  $http = tester.inject('$http');
  $httpBackend = tester.inject('$httpBackend');
  $rootScope = tester.inject('$rootScope');
});
```

This should work, because you are no longer using the ngMock module (which always gets included when you use `angular.mock.module()`). Things should work exactly like you want them to using `ngMidwayTester`.

Comment: Thanks, D. I will try this, probably later today. I do appreciate your clarifications and willingness to indulge me even as I let off some steam. One nagging worry is `$q`. It doesn't appear that  `$q`, `$rootScope`, `$digest` or `$apply` are mocked by *angular-mocks* so I think I'll be on solid ground there. If I can get it all working, I'll have a new plunkr and we'll have a record of this journey for others who are struggling with the same issue. Thx again.

Comment: Progress. Getting the intended behavior with midwayTester. Have not succeeded in devising tests to do a mix of both passthrough and mocked. Working on it.

Comment: We're in business. Thanks, D. [**See working plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/552UuwY6mQGyrMnJMqPx?p=preview). I will write this up shortly.

Comment: Does it mean that the code under the 'Beyond basics' part of the following tutorial cannot work? http://product.moveline.com/testing-angular-apps-end-to-end-with-protractor.html

Comment: That code is fine. It illustrates the correct use of ngmock e2e

Comment: I feel your use of the term "server side" is confusing in this answer. If I understand correctly you're advocating using ngMocksE2E within the context of the Angular application while under test, not in the Jasmine specs (which I agree with) - but a better explanation (IMO) would be to say that ngMocksE2E in this case is executing "client side", i.e. in the browser (wherever that browser may be, on a dev machine or a CI server or whatever).

Comment: @Ward thanks a lot for the plunkr sample, it helped a lot integrating quickkly with ngMidwayTester

Answer (score 23):

I stumbled on the same problem but instead of implementing a rich API or replacing the original angular-mocks simply added in the following helper:

```js
angular.module('httpReal', ['ng'])
    .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', function() {
            return angular.injector(['ng']).get('$httpBackend');
        });
    }])
    .service('httpReal', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        this.submit = function() {
            $rootScope.$digest();
        };
    }]);
```

It patches two issues that prevent an HTTP request from getting passed through:

1. Restores original `$httpBackend`;
2. Provides a method to fulfill the requests, as otherwise they would be in AngularJS' queue waiting for a digest loop.

```js
describe('my service', function() {
    var myService, httpReal;

    beforeEach(module('myModule', 'httpReal'));

    beforeEach(inject(function( _myService_, _httpReal_ ) {
        myService = _myService_;
        httpReal = _httpReal_;
    }));

    it('should return valid data', function(done) {
        myService.remoteCall().then(
            function(data) {
                expect(data).toBeDefined();
                done();
            }, function(error) {
                expect(false).toBeTruthy();
                done();
            });

        httpReal.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: **Clever!**  Coincidentally, I've been thinking about that recently and was going to give it a try. It sure is a light weight alternative to Matthias' [**ngMidwayTester**](https://github.com/yearofmoo/ngMidwayTester). I'm still using ngMidwayTester but I might look at your approach too and see if I prefer it. P.S.: Not entirely sure I'd kick off the digest automatically ... but that's a refinement.

Comment: seems to work for me, but can you better explain the "restoring the original httpBackend"?  Why is that needed?  I would have assumed if you use httpReal that it wouldn't be displacing the httpBackend

Comment: @Hortitude, angular-mocks replaces `$httpBackend` (used internally by `$http`) with its own stub implementation - see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1007.

Comment: @Herman That makes sense, but the part I missed is where $httpBackend is replaced for the real httpBackend?

Comment: @Hortitude `$provide.decorator('$httpBackend', function() {... })` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To test my app with real backend calls I used a [modified version of `angular-mocks`](https://gist.github.com/kyro38/3371aaac54bf6583852f)

It works just like for unit-tests in Jasmine.

I'm using it with Jasmine 2.0, so a test looks like following :

```
it(' myTest', function (done) {
    _myService.apiCall()
        .then(function () {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
            done()
        });
});
```

NB: the `done` is needed because of the async call.

Comment: See Matthias' ["Ng Midway Tester"](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ng-midway-tester) which is what I use when my async tests must make real ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I use to make real HTTP calls when I'm using ngMock for unit tests. I mainly use it for debugging, trying out the API, getting JSON examples etc.

I wrote a more detailed post about the solution on my blog: [How to Unit Test with real HTTP calls using ngMockE2E & passThrough](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/16/unit-test-http-ngmock-passthrough/).

The solution is as follows:

```
angular.mock.http = {};

angular.mock.http.init = function() {

  angular.module('ngMock', ['ng', 'ngMockE2E']).provider({
    $exceptionHandler: angular.mock.$ExceptionHandlerProvider,
    $log: angular.mock.$LogProvider,
    $interval: angular.mock.$IntervalProvider,
    $rootElement: angular.mock.$RootElementProvider
  }).config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$timeout', angular.mock.$TimeoutDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$$rAF', angular.mock.$RAFDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$$asyncCallback', angular.mock.$AsyncCallbackDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$rootScope', angular.mock.$RootScopeDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$controller', angular.mock.$ControllerDecorator);
  }]);

};

angular.mock.http.reset = function() {

  angular.module('ngMock', ['ng']).provider({
    $browser: angular.mock.$BrowserProvider,
    $exceptionHandler: angular.mock.$ExceptionHandlerProvider,
    $log: angular.mock.$LogProvider,
    $interval: angular.mock.$IntervalProvider,
    $httpBackend: angular.mock.$HttpBackendProvider,
    $rootElement: angular.mock.$RootElementProvider
  }).config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$timeout', angular.mock.$TimeoutDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$$rAF', angular.mock.$RAFDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$$asyncCallback', angular.mock.$AsyncCallbackDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$rootScope', angular.mock.$RootScopeDecorator);
    $provide.decorator('$controller', angular.mock.$ControllerDecorator);
  }]);

};
```

Include this source file after ngMock, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-mocks.js"></script>
<!-- this would be the source code just provided -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="ngMockHttp.js"></script>
```

### How to write the test?

```
  describe('http tests', function () {

    beforeEach(module('moviesApp'));

    var $controller;
    var $httpBackend;
    var $scope;

    describe('real http tests', function() {

      beforeEach(angular.mock.http.init);
      afterEach(angular.mock.http.reset);

      beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$httpBackend_) {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $scope = {};
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

        // Note that this HTTP backend is ngMockE2E's, and will make a real HTTP request
        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=terminator').passThrough();
      }));

      it('should load default movies (with real http request)', function (done) {
        var moviesController = $controller('MovieController', { $scope: $scope });

        setTimeout(function() {
          expect($scope.movies).not.toEqual([]);
          done();
        }, 1000);

      });

    });

  });
```

### How it works?

It uses ngMockE2E's version of $httpBackEndProvider, which provides us with the *passThrough* function we see being used in the test. This does as the name suggests and lets a native HTTP call pass through.

We need to re-define the ngMock module without its fake version of the $BrowserProvider, since that is what prevents the real HTTP calls in unit tests that use ngMock.

### Why I do it this way?

I like the flexibility to being able to easily switch between using fakes and real HTTP calls as it helps my workflow when writing the tests, which is why ngMockE2E's version of $httpBackEndProvider is used. It also allows me to code the unit tests in the same way as using ngMock, where I can simply drop in/out the beforeEach/afterEach line to register angular.mock.http.init/reset.

### Plunkr

Here's a [Plunkr with an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pkjg24Tu5jKL3U3p98cL?p=preview).