# Read a HTML file in a Karma+Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular controller that defines an array of over 50 field names. Each of these should occur in an HTML file as both the id and ng-model of an input are present. I would like to test if I made no typos by reading and parsing the HTML file. Since I need to get the array, a Karma+Jasmine test seems ideal (with protractor I can't get that). What would be a good way to test this?

For both the `FileReader` and `$http.get` neither enter the success or error function, and with `XMLHttpRequest` I just get an empty string.

I already added a line

```
pattern: 'app/views/*.html', watched: false, included: false, served: true}
```

to karma.conf.js, that matches the file I want to read.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1.You can use following preprocessor to render html

- npm install karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor --save-dev

Add following into karma.config.js:

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor : {
      moduleName:'templates'
},
```

2.Use $compile service of angular and create html which you want to test and add it to dom. Then you can perform any test on that html

```
var $body=$('$body');
afterEach(
    $body.empty();
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could load the HTML-snippets as fixtures with [`jasmine-jquery`](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#html-fixtures). Don't wonder about the name, it's because the library also adds lots of [custom jasmine matchers](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#jquery-matchers) which are useful in combination with jQuery.

To use it, add the following in your karma config file to the `files` array:

```
// this is the path to your library if installed via bower
'../bower_components/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js', 

// make the views available to the locally by karma started webserver 
{pattern: 'views/*.html', watched: true, served: true, included: false},
```

For your tests, you have to define the path to your views and load them explicitly:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "base/views";  // path to your templates
    jasmine.getFixtures().load('myHtmlSnippet.html');   // load a template
});
```

This will load an `div` with the id `jasmine-fixtures` directly into the `body` of the browser in which the tests run. The loaded fixture will be inserted into the `div#jasmine-fixtures`. Then you can simply access them with jQuery or by vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

After I had such the sample problem to call the "server"-data and don't use a mockup service.
I stumble over this entry: 
[E2E mock $httpBackend doesn't actually passThrough for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864764/e2e-mock-httpbackend-doesnt-actually-passthrough-for-me/26992327#26992327)

Works fine, with this you can use $http.get and check your data.

If you're working with promises try also this: https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/jasmine-as-promised

Comment: I am not doing end to end tests, maybe I should have clarified that. So I don't need this. I actually tried it, but it didn't solve my problem.