# How to substitute $httpBackend with alternate mock server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocking

I have Angular (1.2.x) unit tests where I'm utilizing `ngMock`.  My project has a fixture system that relies on `sinon.fakeServer`.  For my unit tests, I'd prefer to use this as opposed to the `$httpBackend` .

`ngMockE2E` tests Angular provides a `passthrough` method, however there isn't a clear equivalent for unit tests.  The rationale [seems to be](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11879) that unit tests should never be passing-through (to a server) but in my situation I'm just trying to pass through to a non-Angular-dependent-mock.

My strategy right now is to create a shim that matches `.whenGet` and `.whenPost` requests and routes them to my fake server.

However, what would be better is simply "turning off" the `$httpBackend`.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `passThrough`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend

Comment: I did, this apparently only works for `ngMockE2E`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try

```
angular.module('httpReal', ['ng'])
    .config(['$provide', function($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', function() {
            return angular.injector(['ng']).get('$httpBackend');
        });
    }])
    .service('httpReal', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        this.submit = function() {
            $rootScope.$digest();
        };
    }]);
```

This way you can restore httpBackend. 
For more details please refer:  [E2E mock $httpBackend doesn't actually passThrough for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864764/e2e-mock-httpbackend-doesnt-actually-passthrough-for-me)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/16/unit-test-http-ngmock-passthrough/) solution might work.

So the proposition is to use ngMockE2E’s $httpBackend. Actually if your test cause XHR request, it is not a 'Unit Test'.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.